# Why Thread communication is not working in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I am working a small java based game, I am trying to fire missile by player-1 until player-1 doesn't miss target, once Player-1 missed target, then fire tern will move to Player-2, Player-2 will start firing until he miss his target vice versa.

Here Player-1 and Player-2 both are a Java `Runnable` task please find bellow code :

```
public class GameRender implements IGame {
    private Game game;
    private Player player1, player2;
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition notPlayer1TernCondition = lock.newCondition();
    Condition notPlayer2TernCondition = lock.newCondition();

    public GameRender(Game game, Player player1, Player player2) {
        this.game = game;
        this.player1 = player1;
        this.player2 = player2;
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        //ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Player1Task plater1 = new Player1Task(player1.getTargetLocations(), true);
        Player2Task plater2 = new Player2Task(player2.getTargetLocations(), false);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(plater1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(plater2);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void over() {

    }


    class Player1Task implements Runnable {
        private List<TargetLocation> playerOnesTargetLocationList;
        private boolean isHitTarget = false;
        private int fireCount = 0;
        private boolean yourTern;

        Player1Task(List<TargetLocation> playerOnesTargetLocationList, boolean yourTern) {
            this.playerOnesTargetLocationList = playerOnesTargetLocationList;
            this.yourTern = yourTern;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                fire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        private void fire() throws InterruptedException {
            while (fireCount != playerOnesTargetLocationList.size()) {
                if (!yourTern) {
                    notPlayer1TernCondition.await();
                }
                TargetLocation location = playerOnesTargetLocationList.get(fireCount);
                if (player2.getOwnField().hasShip(location.getxPos(), location.getyPos())) {

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Player-1 else");
                    yourTern = false;
                    notPlayer2TernCondition.signalAll();
                }
                fireCount++;
            }

        }

    }

    class Player2Task implements Runnable {
        private List<TargetLocation> playerTwosTargetLocationList;
        private boolean isHitTarget = false;
        private int fireCount = 0;
        private boolean yourTern;

        Player2Task(List<TargetLocation> playerTwosTargetLocationList, boolean youTern) {
            this.playerTwosTargetLocationList = playerTwosTargetLocationList;
            this.yourTern = youTern;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                fire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        private void fire() throws InterruptedException {

            while (fireCount != playerTwosTargetLocationList.size()) {
                if (!yourTern) {
                    notPlayer2TernCondition.await();
                }

                TargetLocation location = playerTwosTargetLocationList.get(fireCount);
                if (player1.getOwnField().hasShip(location.getxPos(), location.getyPos())) {

                } else {
                    System.out.println("p2 else");
                    yourTern = false;
                    notPlayer1TernCondition.signalAll();
                }
                fireCount++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Above code is not working as per expectation, First time Player-1 executes and after that code stuck.

Any explanation is quite appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are never setting yourTern back to true. (A shared variable signifying the which player has the turn can be used instead)**

Explanation:
Assume initially Player1 has the lock and fires as Player1's yourTern is true. Assume it **misses** then you would signal Player2(**which is not yet awaiting**) and set yourTern to false and releases the lock(by calling `notPlayer1TernCondition.await()` method in next iteration). 
This lock will be aquired by Player2 and it would call `notPlayer2TernCondition.await()` as its yourTern is false. 
 **Both thread would now go to awaiting state forever.**